# Time difference in a unix script?

Tags: shell-script

I need to write a script:

```
startdate = 2016-02-14 20:10:10 
enddate =   2016-02-14 23:59:59
c= 1240 (minutes)
d=10  

r = ratio(startdate - enddate) / c;

d=d*r;
```

How to calculate the difference between the start date and the end date?

Comment: _ratio of time difference_ doesn't mean anything to me. Please clarify what you want. Do you want to get the number of seconds (minutes?) between those two dates, so you can compare it to `$c`?

Comment: you may want to convert the start and end date to unix time using the `date` command. thus, subsequent calculation are quite easy to perform.

Comment: What does _hadoop_ have to do with this question?

Answer (score 3):

To calculate seconds between two times:

```
#!/bin/bash

START="2016-02-14 20:10:10"
END="2016-02-14 23:59:59"

SECS=$(echo $(date -d "$END" +%s) - $(date -d "$START" +%s) | bc)

echo $SECS
```

Comment: I dont know the ratio of the start and end date is same as   $(echo $(date -d "$END" +%s) - $(date -d "$START" +%s)

what is | bc in the  script ?

can you please confirm me
Sorry if i am asking wrong question

Comment: hello my c value is minutes, I want to take the ratio of startdate-enddate then that would be divide by c minutes

Comment: Why the construct `SECS=$(echo $(some command pipeline))`? It would be far better to use `SECS=$(some command pipeline)` and avoid a layer of complication.